# Решение с корзиной

Tags: php

Представьте, что покупатель добавил три модема в корзину, и стал дальше бродить по сайту. И спустя время, когда он решил оформить заказ, модемов “В наличии” стало 2 шт (один модем купил кто-то другой) . А в корзине у него висит 3 модема, сейчас у него получится оформить заказ на 3 модема. И тогда в поле “В наличии” число изменится на “-1″.

Чтобы человек не мог оформить заказ на большее кол-во товара, чем есть на складе, нужно всегда после того как пользователь нажимает кнопку “Оформить заказ” делать проверку на соответствие: Число товаров, указанное в корзине, не должно превышать числа, указанного в поле “В наличии” относительно одного товара. Если превосходит, то выдавать сообщение: “Такового-то(здесь указать какой товар) товара на складе: n штук. Пожалуйста, измените кол-во товара в одноименном поле и нажмите “пересчитать” “.

В принципе, я понял, как делать, мы должны после нажатия на кнопку оформить заказ, вызвать БД сравнить кол. товара на складе и количество в корзине, если они >=, то происходит оформление товара, если же <=, то выводит сообщение, что "сори бла бла бла",
вот только в коде я не могу написать.

Comment: Во-первых, на мой взгляд, подход не совсем верный. Представьте, что вы в магазине положили в корзину три бутылки водки и продолжаете дефилировать по рядам. В это время подходит дядя Вася из "сборной гастронома", у которого горят трубы и отбирает у вас одну бутылку. Ваша реакция - легкое недоумение. Во-вторых, что именно вы не можете написать?

Comment: код выборки и сравнения не могу написать количества у меня в корзине и количество в бд

Comment: Ну, это уже для вас сделал господин @Chavez ниже

Answer (score 2):

```
$rate = $_POST['rate'];// получили количество товара, требуемое покупателю
$artikul = $_POST['artikul']; // артикул(уникальный ID товара)
$result = mysql_query("SELECT rate FROM sklad WHERE artikul='$artikul';");// выбрали из БД остаток конкретного товара на складе
$a = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($rate>$a['rate']) 
echo "извините, осталось всего $a['rate'] наименования данного товара";
```